# sed/awk/grep/cut: multiply a number in an xml-attribute by factor of ten

Tags: awk, sed, grep, cut

I would like to multiply the attribute in viewBox of svg-files by a factor of ten.

I want to change
`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1">` to `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" version="1.1"><g transform="scale(10)">`
(I need it for a workaround of a [librsvg-bug](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T36947))

My current script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# defining file
export i=test.svg

#solved librsvg-Bug T194192 https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T194192
sed -ri "s/<svg([-[:alnum:]=\"\.\/: ]*) viewBox=\"0,0,([[:digit:]\.]*),([[:digit:]\.]*)\"/<svg viewBox=\"0 0 \2 \3\"\1/g" $i


#put viewBox at the beginning (otherwise I will have a variable to less)
sed -ri 's/<svg([-[:alnum:]=\" \.\/:\,\(\)_#]+) viewBox="([-[:digit:] \.]+)"([-[:alnum:]=\" \.\/:\,\(\);#]*)>/<svg viewBox="\2"\1\3>/' $i
sed -ri 's/\r/\n/g' $i

#Define file as a variable
export h=$(sed -r 's/<svg viewBox="([-[:digit:]]+) ([-[:digit:]]+) ([[:digit:]]+)\.([[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]*) ([[:digit:]]+)\.([[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]*)"([-[:alnum:]=\" \.\/:\,\(\)_;]+)>/<svg viewBox="\1 \2 \3\4.\50 \6\7.\80"\9><g transform="scale(10)">/' $i)

#Reading out the relevant line
export j=$(ls -l|grep -E "viewBox=\"[-[:digit:].]{1,8} [-[:digit:].]{1,8} [[:digit:].]{2,11} [[:digit:].]{2,11}" $i)

#Insert a special character to define the point of splitting
export l=$(echo $j | sed -e "s/viewBox=\"/>/g" )

#split at this special character and take the part afterwards
export m=$(echo $l | cut -f2 -d">")

#Multiply the four numbers by a factor of 10
export n=$(echo $m | awk  '{printf "%f %f %f %f\n",$1*10,$2*10,$3*10,$4*10}')

#Replace the old four numbers with the new four numbers
sed -ri "s/<svg([-[:alnum:]=\" \.\/:;\,#]*) viewBox=\"[-[:digit:]\.]+ [-[:digit:]\.]+ [[:digit:]\.]+ [[:digit:]\.]+\"([-[:alnum:]=\" \.\/:\,#\(\)_;]+)>/<svg\1 viewBox=\"$n\"\2>\n<g transform=\"scale(10)\">/" $i
```

This is neither beautiful, nor always working. (for example it won't work if there is an inline svg in an mother-svg embedded ([example](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dzia%C5%82anie_d%C5%82awika_przeciwzwarciowego_1_Workaround.svg)))

You can use whatever you want it should:

- Work on Ubuntu aswell on Cygwin
- should be a batchcommand

Comment: Is it an absolute requirement that you use `sed`?  It's suited neither to XML parsing, nor to arithmetic.  `awk` can handle arithmetic, but to handle complex files you would need a dedicated XML parser (such as [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php)).

Comment: @JigglyNaga The slight issue here is that xmlstarlet can't really poke inside the text attribute to modify its values.  One would have to extract it, modify it by other means, and update the XML with the modified text string.

Comment: @JigglyNaga I you know a working solution I would be happy. (sorry for the missleading title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use perl to do math in your regex:

```
perl -pe 's/viewBox="(\d+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+)"/"viewBox=\"".($1*10)." ".($2*10)." ".($3*10)." ".($4*10)."\""/eg' <input file>
```

It could be cleaned up somewhat by making it a full script rather than a single line. At which point I would probably pull out the math in regex and replace it with a loop across the values in viewBox.